# Sorbet and tapioca unable to detect a class from require_relative

Tags: sorbet

I have a file in a Sinatra app, `config/environment.rb`:

```rb
class Environment
  def self.test?
    RACK_ENV == 'test'
  end
```

and another one `api/middleware/error_handler.rb`

```rb
require_relative '../../config/environment'
# ...
    rescue StandardError => e
      raise if ::Environment.test?
```

This throws a typecheck error:

```
api/middleware/error_handler.rb:34: Unable to resolve constant Environment https://srb.help/5002
    34 |      raise if ::Environment.test?
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried various things:

- Defining a shim that declares a ::Environment class
- Defining function type signatures in `config/environment.rb`
- Renaming the class defined in `config/environment.rb` to `Environment2` and updating the reference in the other file

None of these work. Any ideas why this is failing in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `sorbet/config` had this in it:

```
--ignore=config/
```

Removing that resolved this error.